# Get item Count from multiple mentioned list based on search query

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I have 3 Sharepoint lists named has  list1 list2 and list3 there are 2 common fields in all the lists.
I want to get the itemscount/items from all the this 3lists && filtering the data with 2columns

EX- Get count of Items/ItemCount from 3lists where Status="active" && Email="someone@gmail.com"

using SPO Rest Api

Answer (score 1):

rest api can only get items from one list at the same time. You can refer to the following url

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('list1')/items?$filter=(Status = 'active' and Email = 'someone@gmail.com')
```